# PHP to fetch JSON from JQUERY

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-form-validator

I wanted to use [server side validation by jQuery Form Validator](http://www.formvalidator.net/#security-validators_backend).  My understanding is there is an option to pass additional parameter to the server in form of JSON.  The following snippet is from their website:

```html
<?php 
  $json = json_encode(array('user'=>$user->get('ID'))); 
?>

<p>
  <strong>E-mail:</strong>
  <input type="email" 
         name="check-email" 
         data-validation="server" 
         data-validation-url="/validate-form-input.php" 
         data-validation-param-name="email" 
         data-validation-req-params="<?php echo $json ?>" />
</p>
```

Can anyone show me how to get the user ID in validate-form-input.php as per the code shown above?  Thanks.

Comment: see /validate-input.php on the page you provided

Comment: Isn't that snippet only demonstrating the code for validating the input field on the form?  Correct me from wrong, there is an option to pass additional parm using "data-validation-req-params", I don't know how to get the value passed from this.

Comment: var_dump your $_GET variable you should see the additional parameters there

Comment: I dumped $_POST data to a log file and it shows a:1:{s:9:"post_data";a:2:{s:4:"user";s:1:"1";s:5:"email";s:20:"john@homel.com";}}, How do I get the value of 1 (after "user")?

Comment: I figured it out.  Just simply get the value in $_POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$user = $_POST['user'];
```

I simply get it from $_POST.